# Member function not accessible in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have two class hierarchies A and B, where A objects have a pointer to B objects.

```
class AbstractB{
public:
    AbstractB(){};
    virtual ~AbstractB(){};
    virtual void printVal() = 0;
protected:
    int val;
};

class AbstractA{
public:
    AbstractA(){};
    virtual ~AbstractA(){};
    virtual void printVal() = 0;
protected:
    AbstractB* b;
};

class B1 : public AbstractB{
public:
    B1(): AbstractB(){ val = 1; };
    virtual void printVal(){ std::cout << val; };
    void foo(){ std::cout << "foo"; };
};

class A1 : public AbstractA{
public:
    A1(): AbstractA(){ b = new B1; };
    virtual void printVal(){ b->printVal(); }
    void foo(){ b->foo(); };
};
```

Compiler complaints about the second to last line "Error: AbstractB has no member "foo". I don't understand this, since I construct a B1 object in the A1 constructor, which has a member foo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer `b` is of type `AbstractB` which does not have the `foo` member function. Even though the only instatiable derived type of `AbstractB` has a `foo` member function the parent type does not and if you made other types derived from `AbstractB` they might not have `foo`.

I see 3 options:

1. Add `foo` to `AbstractB`.
2. Make the pointer on `A1` a pointer to a `B1`.
3. (Please don't) Use some kind of cast in the foo member function on `A1`.

Comment: I cannot add foo to AbstractB, because it's specific to B1. B2 may have bar() instead. 2) is the obvious solution but isn't there some way to avoid coupling the concretions. I've been told over and over again, you should couple abstractions, not concretions?

Comment: You can add virtual foo() to AbstractB and you should. The only specific thing should be the implementation detail, not the API.

Comment: but If I derive 100 different classes from AbstractB, I'd have to add 100 virtual  functions to AbstractB, which does not make sense, because each one will just be implemented in exactly one derived class. foo() has nothing to do with AbstractB, it's 100% specific to B1. There has to be a way to construct the correct B1 object in the A1 constructor. Isn't there some kind of Design Pattern for this? Why shouldn't I use a cast btw?

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner You only need to add member functions for each class you add, not each member function. If they all have different function then why do they share a common interface?

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner Adding the cast raises different issues based on the kind of cast you are adding. The biggest issue is that it breaks abstraction/encapsulation by forcing A1 to know which type of AbstractB it uses. It means that changes to things in the APIs of the various B classes could require internal changes to A1. As for issues with specific casts, static_cast could work but will enforce the ties at compile time; dynamic_cast could fail at runtime without ever breaking(but can be checked at least) the build; reinterpret_cast could break at runtime and can't readily be checked.

Comment: @ Sqeaky, I have tried to provide a minimal example here. The situation is that all derived Bs share most of the interface of AbstractB, but each derived B has a few methods that are entirely specific to them, i.e. not shared. If I followed your advise it would imply that I would have to add virtual functions to the AbstractB class for each of these specific functions, even though they are only specific to exactly one derived B. It should be clear that when I construct, say an A4 object that it needs a pointer to a B4 object, and not a B. Am I going about this in a fundamentally wrong way?

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner What you are doing is promising the compiler that all these items look like ducks, quack like ducks and behave like ducks, the asking them to moo and bark.

Figure out some way to be more generic with the functions you provide even it it means adding empty functions to your abstract class. Perhaps you have a frobnicate function and some Bs need to do work before and after it. Add a pre_frobnicate and post_frobnicate to AbstractB that are empty by default but a B can override to do useful work. Then in A you call them knowing they will work when needed but often do nothing.

Comment: @Squeaky, I think I'll go with your suggestion number 2: Make the pointer on A1 a pointer to a B1. That will definitely keep the number of lines of code under control. Otherwise, I'd have to keep modifying the base class when adding new derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

Field b is of type AbstractB* and you can only use methods and fields that are present in AbstractB class. 
In fact b can point to any subclass of AbstractB, not all of them will have foo field.

Comment: why is this the case and how can I fix this? I am planning on having multiple derived classes from A and B, e.g. A1, A2, A3,... B1, B2, B3,... such that Ai can only hold a Bi. I don't want to put a pointer into every derived class of A, the whole thing should work polymorphically.

Comment: I don't see your point. Why use pointer to base class if you want to use only specific one B1. Why do you want to pay for polymorphism if you plan not to use it. It is also place for errors if by mistake you instead of B1 create B2.

Comment: Tomasz, Did you read my last comment? I am planning on deriving multiple classes from AbstractA and AbstractB, and each type of A will have a pointer to a specific type of B. Instead of defining a member variable in each derived A class, I want to express this relationship in the base classes? This would make heavy use of polymorphism.

Comment: My point is that adding pointer to each subclass to avoid polymorphism is the proper way of doing things here since you want to use specyfic class Bi for Ai. And not use common interface AbstractB but specyfic features of Bi.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have specific subclass Bi for each subclass Ai I would sugest to add template class in the middle between AbstractA and A1. 
This will save you some work and it is safe to use.

```
class AbstractB{
public:
    AbstractB(){};
    virtual ~AbstractB(){};
    virtual void printVal() = 0;
protected:
    int val;
};

class AbstractA{
public:
    AbstractA(){};
    virtual ~AbstractA(){};
    virtual void printVal() = 0;
};

template<typename BType>
class AbstractAwithPointerTo : public AbstractA{
public:
    AbstractAwithPointerTo(BType * p = 0) : b(p) {}
protected:
    BType * b;
};

class B1 : public AbstractB{
public:
    B1(): AbstractB(){ val = 1; };
    virtual void printVal(){ std::cout << val; }
    void foo(){ std::cout << "foo"; }
};

class A1 : public AbstractAwithPointerTo<B1>{
public:
    A1(): AbstractAwithPointerTo(new B1) {}
    virtual void printVal(){ b->printVal(); }
    void foo(){ b->foo(); };
};
```